# Migrate security-realm configuration from wildfly 8 to 26

Tags: migration, wildfly-8, wildfly-26

I want to migrate security-realm from standalone.xml on WildFly 8 to WildFly 26.1.x. Can someone help me how to migrate this configuration tag to 26.1.x

```
            <security-realm name="Realm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="/folder/keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="****"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <truststore path="/folder/cacerts" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="****"/>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
```